# What is the 'u' parameter estimated by Statsmodel's ARIMA fit method?

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I'm struggling to find mention of the `'u'` parameter that is returned by the statsmodels [ARIMA.fit](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.fit) method in the following ARMAX model parameter estimation example:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA

# Sample of the full input-output dataset
id_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'u': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'y': [-1.4369, -0.999, -0.0325, 0.8435, 0.4339, -0.2925, 
          -0.8885, -2.3191, -4.004, -5.4779, -7.053, -7.5489, 
          -8.779, -8.9262, -8.5207, -8.3915, -8.5699, -8.2192, 
          -8.284, -7.6011]
})

arma22 = ARIMA(id_data.y, exog=id_data.u, order=(2, 0, 2), trend='n').fit()
print(arma22.params)
print(arma22.summary())
```

Output:

```
u        -0.564553
ar.L1     1.798081
ar.L2    -0.829465
ma.L1    -0.859744
ma.L2     0.998002
sigma2    0.220407
dtype: float64
                               SARIMAX Results                                
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                   20
Model:                 ARIMA(2, 0, 2)   Log Likelihood                 -18.559
Date:                Sun, 25 Feb 2024   AIC                             49.119
Time:                        14:26:11   BIC                             55.093
Sample:                             0   HQIC                            50.285
                                 - 20                                         
Covariance Type:                  opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u             -0.5646      0.303     -1.861      0.063      -1.159       0.030
ar.L1          1.7981      0.158     11.407      0.000       1.489       2.107
ar.L2         -0.8295      0.164     -5.059      0.000      -1.151      -0.508
ma.L1         -0.8597     21.365     -0.040      0.968     -42.735      41.016
ma.L2          0.9980     49.501      0.020      0.984     -96.022      98.018
sigma2         0.2204     10.881      0.020      0.984     -21.106      21.547
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   1.05   Jarque-Bera (JB):                 0.81
Prob(Q):                              0.31   Prob(JB):                         0.67
Heteroskedasticity (H):               0.78   Skew:                             0.27
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.76   Kurtosis:                         2.18
===================================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Covariance matrix calculated using the outer product of gradients (complex-step).
```

I was expecting an ARMAX(2, 2) model to have four parameters (four degrees of freedom).  I've turned off the trend (`const`) parameter so it can't be that.

There is a worked-example of an ARMAX(1, 1) model [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_sarimax_stata.html#ARIMA-Example-4:-ARMAX-(Friedman)) but no `u` parameter appears in the results.

If someone can point me to part of the documentation which mentions what 'u' is I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the answer to my own question.

If you pass raw data instead of a Pandas series the 'u' parameter turns to 'x1' as in the examples in the documentation.

```
arma22 = ARIMA(id_data.y.values, exog=id_data.u.values, order=(2, 0, 2), trend='n').fit()
print(arma22.params)
print(arma22.summary())
```

Output:

```
[-0.56455335  1.79808108 -0.82946546 -0.85974377  0.99800247  0.22040651]
                               SARIMAX Results                                
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                   20
Model:                 ARIMA(2, 0, 2)   Log Likelihood                 -18.559
Date:                Sun, 25 Feb 2024   AIC                             49.119
Time:                        14:58:40   BIC                             55.093
Sample:                             0   HQIC                            50.285
                                 - 20                                         
Covariance Type:                  opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1            -0.5646      0.303     -1.861      0.063      -1.159       0.030
ar.L1          1.7981      0.158     11.407      0.000       1.489       2.107
ar.L2         -0.8295      0.164     -5.059      0.000      -1.151      -0.508
ma.L1         -0.8597     21.365     -0.040      0.968     -42.735      41.016
ma.L2          0.9980     49.501      0.020      0.984     -96.022      98.018
sigma2         0.2204     10.881      0.020      0.984     -21.106      21.547
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   1.05   Jarque-Bera (JB):                 0.81
Prob(Q):                              0.31   Prob(JB):                         0.67
Heteroskedasticity (H):               0.78   Skew:                             0.27
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.76   Kurtosis:                         2.18
===================================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Covariance matrix calculated using the outer product of gradients (complex-step).
```

So the `'u'` in fact comes from the Pandas series name of my exogenous inputs.

So I'm guessing `'u'` (or `'x1'`) is the beta parameter in this ARMAX model definition, which I found on the [FAQ page](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_sarimax_faq.html#Using-exog-in-SARIMAX-and-ARIMA):

[image]

If someone can confirm this that would be great.  Or point me to the part of the document that explains the parameters of the ARIMA model and the `model.summary()` and `model.params` outputs.